# word frequency in a pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, pdf

I found this code on git hub and I can't get it to work. The point is to convert the pdf to .txt then list all the words with frequency of occurrence. I'm beginning to learn python but I'm not very good yet. I am getting this tracebac

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python38\Keyword-Extracter-master\keyword_extract_with_weight.py", line 31, in <module>
    keywords = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\w+',text)
  File "C:\python_3.9\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Here's the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PyPDF2
import textract
import re

filename ='test.pdf' 

pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')               
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)   
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages                 


count = 0
text = ""
                                                            
while count < num_pages:                       
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
    
if text != "":
    text = text
 
else:
    text = textract.process('words.txt', method='tesseract', language='eng')


text = text.encode('ascii','ignore').lower()
keywords = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\w+',text)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(keywords)),columns=['keywords'])



def weightage(word,text,number_of_documents=1):
    word_list = re.findall(word,text)
    number_of_times_word_appeared =len(word_list)
    tf = number_of_times_word_appeared/float(len(text))
    idf = np.log((number_of_documents)/float(number_of_times_word_appeared))
    tf_idf = tf*idf
    return number_of_times_word_appeared,tf,idf ,tf_idf 


    
df['number_of_times_word_appeared'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[0])
df['tf'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[1])
df['idf'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[2])
df['tf_idf'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[3])

df = df.sort_values('tf_idf',ascending=True)
df.head(25)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python3 has two different *string* types. `bytes` and `str`.  Different API will work on different types.  The error is telling you that `re` wants to deal with `str` not `bytes`.  The line `text = text.encode('ascii','ignore').lower()` turns your text into `bytes`.  So you will need to turn it back into a string with `decode()`, or never convert it to a byte-string in the first place.

Comment: Thanks So much I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PyPDF2
import textract
import re

filename ='test.pdf' 

pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')               
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)   
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages                 


count = 0
text = ""
                                                            
while count < num_pages:                       
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
    
if text != "":
    text = text
 
else:
    text = textract.process('words.txt', method='tesseract', language='eng')


text = text.encode('ascii','ignore').lower()
text_decoded = text.decode()
keywords = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\w+',text_decoded)


df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(keywords)),columns=['keywords'])



def weightage(word,text,number_of_documents=1):
    word_list = re.findall(word,text_decoded)
    number_of_times_word_appeared =len(word_list)
    tf = number_of_times_word_appeared/float(len(text_decoded))
    idf = np.log((number_of_documents)/float(number_of_times_word_appeared))
    tf_idf = tf*idf
    return number_of_times_word_appeared,tf,idf ,tf_idf 



    
df['number_of_times_word_appeared'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[0])
df['tf'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[1])
df['idf'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[2])
df['tf_idf'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: weightage(x,text)[3])

df = df.sort_values('tf_idf',ascending=True)
df.head(25)     
df.to_csv('out_put.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

'''